# Easiest way to distribute python command-line tool to others?

Tags: python, c++, shell

I'm a student working alongside a research group from the biology department. The problems they deal with on a daily basis are solvable using computers. I wrote some python code to make their lives easier, but the problem I'm running into is distribution. Specifically, the problem is guiding them in installing the necessary libraries.

I've written a shell script that does the bulk of the work (basically a collection of "pip3 install moduleName" calls), but I've recently noticed that window's cmd doesn't run shell scripts. Furthermore, windows don't come with a C++ compiler preinstalled, which is necessary for some of the libraries.

So, I'm starting to realize that a command-line tool is just not feasible. Are there alternative approaches to this obstacle? I've considered building a GUI, but I'm not sure how that's going to solve my problem. I know that a lot of apps come with an "installation wizard". I've never worked with such a thing, so I'm not sure how involved the work is to build one. Perhaps sending them an executable would work better?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using setuptools to package it?

Comment: I have not. Should I be doing that? Right now, the program is just a directory of python scripts.

Comment: It can package all python modules, but as far as I know, it won't be able to package C++ compilers and all that.

Comment: Packaging a C++ compiler to send python doesn't sound right. What dependencies require that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

It should be help you.

Bests regards,
Emmanuel

Comment: It creates standalone executable (which doesn't require to have python to be run)

Answer (score 0):

So the best way would be to use `setuptools` to package your module and upload it to PyPi. This way, users would be able to set it up using a simple `pip install your-package-name`.

[Here](https://github.com/ssundarraj/image-resize/blob/master/setup.py) is a simple command line tool that I packaged with setuptools. It'll give you a good idea as to how it works.

Also, here's a [setuptools guide](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows I would recommend  WinPython Portable. It has a QT GUI and almost all scientific modules pre-installed. It also can easily be extended via its control panel with fancier modules like pyqtgraph. You just make a single installation that satisfies your needs and then copy it to other computers. http://winpython.sourceforge.net/